# How to structure PHP Modules?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I have a question for you. I'm not sure how to structure a PHP Module for CMS maybe when I create a new Page I want to select the Module which are created, for example
News Module, Gallery Module etc..

How can I structure this and implement those modules in PHP CMS ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is way too broad. You will need to add some detail about what aspect of "structuring" you mean. Also, it's probably impossible to answer because we don't know anything about your CMS

Comment: So I mean how to call the module from mysql database or from directories

Comment: Can anyone help me in this question ??

Comment: not really, I think it's still too hazy to answer meaningfully. It would be better if you could break down the issue to specific questions, maybe show some code /  file structures you have

Answer (score 3):

In your database you should hold a modules table that consists of the following:

- id
- module_name
- module_desc
- module_folder
- module_active

so that you can keep modules organized, in the table where you have `module_folder` this should be the location of the module such as

```
cms_root() . "/modules/%module_folder%/main.module.php"
```

This is where interfaces would come in handy :)

```
interface IModule
{
    public function __run($param);
    public function __version();
    public function __shutdown();
    //...
}
```

you should also have a class called `Module` where the module would extend and gather rights to templates/database ect.

```
class Module
{
    public $DB,$TPL; /*...*/

     /*
         Functions ehre to help the module gain access to the instance of the page.
     */
}
```

Also the Module class should be able to execute modules and keep track of executed modules, so in your core code you can say `$Module->RunAll()` and it would run them.

A module file would probably look like:

```
class Gallery_Module extends Module implements IModule
{
    public function __version()
    {
         return '1.0';
    }

    public function __run()
    {
         //Assign module data to the template :)
    }

    public function __shutdown()
    {
         //Clean old records etc from DB
    }
}
```

And within your core as said above, you can get the Module class to read active modules from the database load the files from the folder and create an instance of the class, followed by there execution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this will Help me, but since when I create a New Page and want to Select the Module Photo Gallery to show all images, how to make this, can you help me ?

Comment: As Pekka says, we don't know that much information to help you to the extent that your asking, you will need a many to many database relationship to assign modules to pages.

Comment: Have you any kind of examples which are created by you, that will help me ?